# "missing right parenthesis" error in oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to query the last x minutes of data from a table called V_DISPOSITIVO
I have the following query (for example, x= 10 minutes):

```
SELECT FECHA
  FROM V_DISPOSITIVO
 WHERE FECHA > (select FECHA  - interval '10' minute 
                  from V_DISPOSITIVO  
                 where (rownum = 1) 
              order by FECHA desc)
```

It fails, but the output doesn't give me the exact cause it fails. It just says

> Error code 907, SQL state 42000: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Something in your code doesn't make sense, is that - interval '10' minute line supposed to be a comment?

Comment: @JacobH, no it shouldn't be.

Comment: @JacobH. `interval '10' minute` is the SQL standard syntax for writing an interval value

Comment: Did you mean: `WHERE FECHA > sysdate - interval '10' minute`?

Comment: "somedate - interval '10' minute" is a valid oracle operation to substract time from a date. For example, select FECHA  - interval '10' minute from V_DISPOSITIVO  where (rownum = 1) order by FECHA desc returns 2017-05-07 23:50:00.000

Comment: Maybe in oracle but it's nowhere near standard SQL... thanks for the clarification though.

Comment: @JacobH: that **is** 100% standard SQL.

Comment: @JacobH Interval literals in [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00221), [SQL server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/interval-literals), [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need the date of the last row saved (it could be 2 years ago), and then substract x minutes from that.

There is no such thing as the "last" row in a relational database. If you mean the "latest" value in a date or timestamp column, simply use `max()` and substract the 10 minutes:

```
SELECT fecha
FROM v_dispositivo
WHERE fecha > (SELECT max(FECHA)  - interval '10' minute 
               FROM v_dispositivo);
```

Comment: Yes this is right. I believe in his original code, it would yield the same result if the `- interval '10' minute` was moved to the very end, after the last parenthesis (but your solution is "cleaner"). Then again I don't know why the error was raised in the first place :)

Comment: Thanks. This one was the correct solution for my problem. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I assume "fecha" is a a datetime column. If so, try the following instead

```
SELECT FECHA
FROM V_DISPOSITIVO
WHERE FECHA > sysdate - 10/(60*24)
```

or

```
WHERE FECHA > sysdate - interval '10' minute
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. But this is not what I need. I need the date of the last row saved (it could be 2 years ago), and then substract x minutes from that.

Comment: So basically you want the most recent record and any older record that is less than 10 minutes "older" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single query using an analytic function (and eliminating the sub-query):

```
SELECT FECHA
FROM   (
  SELECT FECHA,
         MAX( FECHA ) OVER () AS MAX_FECHA
  FROM   V_DISPOSITIVO
)
WHERE  FECHA > MAX_FECHA - INTERVAL '10' MINUTE;
```